# Website redirects itself to annoying ad pages

Tags: web, cpanel

I am currently developing website, continuing a task handed by my senior.
But since the first time it is handed to me, the website keeps redirecting itself to ad pages. It happens only on the website I develop, not to the others, so the problem is not in the browser.

Is it something in the code? Where specifically do I need to look for it and disable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling redirects will arise as a huge problem in the future development. There must be some asynchronous scripts running in the background, with reference to an **iframe** or redirecting the webpage to some **advertisements** as follows:

`<script async type="text/javascript" src="examplead.js"></script>`

Removing scripts like them can solve the issue.

Comment: Okay gonna check it for now. Thanks